# Estimating pi from darts being thrown at a SPHERICAL dartboard (python)

Tags: python, probability, pi

The familiar code for estimating pi is as follows:

```
import math,random
random.seed(777)
j = pie = 1
while True:
    pie = pie + math.trunc(random.random()**2 + random.random()**2)
    if j%100000==0: print(4*(1-float(pie)/float(j)))
    j = j + 1
print('done')
```

which emulates darts being thrown at a two-dimensional dartboard.
But when you try to elevate to a three-dimensional dartboard with:

```
import math,random
random.seed(777)
j = pie = 1
while True:
    pie = pie + math.trunc(random.random()**2 + random.random()**2 + random.random()**2)
    if j%100000==0: print((3.0/4.0)*8.0*(1-float(pie)/float(j)))
    j = j + 1
print('done')
```

you get something other than pi.

Comment: @Bob__ still doesn't work.

Comment: You could write it [differently](https://godbolt.org/z/7r167YheK), but it still has an extremely *slow* convergence rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I agree with the solution proposed by @Bob__ as it's more straightforward.
Having said that, your solution can be generalized to 3 dimensional dartboard:

```
import math,random

random.seed(777)
j = pie = 1
pie = 0
while True:
    # pie = pie + math.trunc(random.random()**2 + random.random()**2 + random.random()**2)
    pie = pie + min(1, math.trunc(random.random()**2 + random.random()**2 + random.random()**2))
    if j%100000==0: print((3.0/4.0)*8.0*(1-float(pie)/float(j)))
    j = j + 1
print('done')
```

To understand the issue we need to clarify what the `pie` variable really does. It contains the number of cases where a random radius is longer than 1.0 (so beyond the 3D dartboard).

The 2D case works because `math.trunc` always returns either 0 or 1 (in or out) but for 3D it returns either 0 or 1 or 2. So, in case of 3D, it fails because it sometimes increases `pie` by 2 and, thus, converges faster.

To fix your example, you just need to make sure that `pie` is never increased by more than 1 at a time.

Comment: ahhh, thank you! The corners of a cube are more than 1.5 times the radius (of a sphere nested within itself) from the center. Didn't think of that.
```
import math,random
random.seed(777)
j = pie = 1
while True:
 pie = pie + math.trunc((random.random()**2 + random.random()**2 + random.random()**2)**(0.5))
 if j%100000==0: print((3.0/4.0)*8.0*(1-float(pie)/float(j)))
 j = j + 1
print('done')
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. If my suggestion resolves your issue then consider marking it as answer to your question.